# Problem 20 from Herstein's book

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

Let $G$ be a group such that $(ab)^p=a^pb^p$ for all $a,b\in G,$ where $p$ is a prime number. Let $S=\{x\in G: x^{p^m}=e \quad \text{for some $m$ depending on $x$}\}$. Prove

(a) $S$ is  anormal subgroup of $G$

(b) If $\bar{G}=G/S$ and if $\bar{x}\in \bar{G}$ is such that $\bar{x}^p=\bar{e}$ then $\bar{x}=\bar{e}$.

**Proof:** (a) We need to show that $gSg^{-1}\subset S$ for any $g\in G$. Indeed, if $x\in gSg^{-1}$ then $x=gsg^{-1}$ and $s^{p^m}=e$. Hence $x^{p^m}=(gsg^{-1})^{p^m}=gs^{p^m}g^{-1}=geg^{-1}=e$. Thus $x\in S$ and we have shown that $gSg^{-1}\subset S$.

(b) Since $S$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ then $\bar{G}=G/S$ is group. In other words we should prove that if $Sg^p=S$ $\Rightarrow$ $Sg=S$.

**Proof:** I) Let $z\in Sg$ $\Rightarrow$ $z=s_1g=s_2g^pg$ since $s_1\in S=Sg^p$ and $s_1^{p^k}=s_2^{p^r}=e$. 
Then: $e=(s_1)^{p^{k+r}}=(s_2g^p)^{p^{k+r}}=s_2^{p^{k+r}}g^{p^{k+r+1}}=g^{p^{k+r+1}}$ then

$z^{p^{k+r+1}}=(s_1g)^{p^{k+r+1}}=s_1^{p^{k+r+1}}g^{p^{k+r+1}}=e$. Hence $z\in S$ $\Rightarrow$ $Sg\subset S$

II) Let $z\in S$ $\Rightarrow$ $z=s_1=(\text{since $S=Sg^p$})=s_2g^p=s_2g^{p-1}g$. Since $S$ is normal subgroup of $G$ then $s_2=g^ps_3g^{-p}$ and putting that into above we derive $=g^ps_3g^{-p}g^{p-1}g=\underbrace{(g^ps_3g^{-1})}_{x} g=xg$

We need to show that $x\in S$. Since $s_1,s_2,s_3\in S$ then $s_1^{p^k}=s_2^{p^l}=s_3^{p^r}=e$

$e=(s_2)^{p^{k+l+r}}=(s_1g^{-p})^{p^{k+l+r}}=(g^{-1})^{p^{l+k+r+1}}$ $\Rightarrow$ $g^{p^{l+k+r+1}}=e$ $\Rightarrow$ $(g^p)^{p^{k+l+r}}=e$

$s_3^{p^{l+k+r+1}}=e$

It's quite obvious that if we take $\nu=p^{l+k+r+1}p^{l+k+r}=p^{2(l+k+r)+1}$ then $x^{\nu}=(g^ps_3g^{-1})^{\nu}=e$. So $x\in S$ then $z=xg\in Sg$. Thus, $S\subset Sg$. Combining these inclusions we get $Sg=S$.

**Remark:** It's obvious that if $(ab)^p=a^pb^p$ then $(ab)^{p^m}=a^{p^m}b^{p^m}$. However, why $p$ is just a prime number I did not understand.

Is my solution correct? Mostly I am interested in b) since a) is quite trivial.

Comment: Apologies if this is obvious, why is $(gsg^{-1})^{p^m}=gs^{p^m}g^{-1}$ true?

Comment: @KyleBroder $$(gsg^{-1})^k=\overbrace{gsg^{-1}gsg^{-1}\ldots gsg^{-1}}^\text{$k$ times}$$

Comment: @KyleBroder, $(gsg^{-1})^n=(gsg^{-1})(gsg^{-1})\dots (gsg^{-1})=gs^ng^{-1}$

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thanks

Comment: @KyleBroder, so what do you think about my proof?